# How can I use grep to remove extraneous entries from Unity's logcat output?

Tags: unity-game-engine, grep, adb, logcat

You get logcat output from Unity by using the following command;

```
adb logcat -s Unity
```

Here is a typical log message that each output call would generate;

```
02-16 09:17:09.245 18683 27815 I Unity   : I [HTTPRequest]: Sending request: POST /ws/1/entry/1/global HTTP/1.1
02-16 09:17:09.245 18683 27815 I Unity   :
02-16 09:17:09.245 18683 27815 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
```

How can I use `grep` to return the first line above but not the 2nd or 3rd lines? I know that I can use `-v` to invert the matching, and therefore can remove the 'DebugBindings' line using the following;

```
 adb logcat -s Unity | grep -v DebugBindings
```

But how can I also exclude the empty lines?

Comment: may be check if line ends with `:` or `Unity   :` etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Ev '^.*?Unity\s*:$' file
```

-E            grep with extended-regexp

.*?Unity      allow all characters until first occurrence of the word "Unity"

\s*:$         allow any number of spaces followed by : and end of line

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately running `adb logcat -s Unity | grep -Ev '^.*?Unity\s*:$'` returns the same results as `adb logcat -s Unity`. Would any of this be dependant on how the reg ex is interpreted? I am using cygwin on Windows with the grep plugin.

Comment: I would try to output to file `adb logcat -s Unity > file` and play with grepping the file `grep -Ev '^.*?Unity\s*:$' file`. Then play with this pattern to see what catches the empty line and not anything else. try maybe '^.*?Unity\s*:\W*$'.